# Alternative to passing activity to Repository

Tags: android, firebase, architecture, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata

According to this image on the [Guide to Android App Architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#overview), and some other material that I have watched and/or read, objects at a higher level of the architecture hierarchy should have instances to (and only to) objects that are lower in the hierarchy. For example, the `Activity` can instantiate the `ViewModel` and the `ViewModel` can instantiate the `Repository`. I also understand that the repository is supposed to interact with the data source and provide a clean API for all of the app to use. Additionally, the `ViewModel` (or even the `repository` for that matter) should never have an instance to the Activity that it is servicing. [image: Android Architecture guide]

In my app, I am using `Firebase Cloud Firestore` to store my user data, and I want to update my data in real-time. FireStore API provides a nice way to clean up the listeners when the underlying Activity Stops, that is the 
`addSnapshotListener(Activity activity, EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> listener` method for the `DocumentReference` class. According to my understanding of the Architecture guide, all these listeners should be present in the Repository class. So to make the listener stop when the Activity stops, I'll have to pass an instance to the Activity into the Repository. This is not advised as if the activity configuration changes, it causes a memory leak.

The other solution would be to create the listener in the Activity class but that violates the [Seperation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle and in general makes the activity kind of clunky.

The third solution is I manually remove the listener from the Activity's `OnDestroy()` (or `OnStop()` whatever) method. But that seems like a bad idea because what happens if there are multiple listeners to the data that all need to be active at the same time? I'll have to keep track of all of them and all that seems like a lot of work that the `FireBase` API has already handled for me.

How do I go about this problem? Can the `LifeCycle` classes provide a solution? Or do I just screw the Architecture guide?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question and after looking at [Handling Lifecycles with Lifecycle-Aware Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) I can think of the listener being passed from the Activity/Fragment into the ViewModel and from there to the repository where you would be able to get the lifecycle events and act accordingly.

Unfortunately, because the repository needs to know about the lifecycle changes you can not have an entirely decoupled repository as it needs to know about the lifecycle events (LifecycleOwner).

Having this listener passed into the ViewModel or Repository doesn't seem too bad, although you may be able to use the ViewModel [`onCreared()`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle) since ViewModel is lifecycle-aware.

From the `ViewModel.onCleared()` you could call the repository to stop listening for snapshot changes. However, this would have to be managed manually but then you wouldn't have to worry about a reference from the activity in your repository.

Comment: Passing the Listener into the viewModel seems like a good idea. Each viewModel can have it's own seperate listeners and I'll just remove them in onCleared